# Not getting correct json response as expected actual response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

This is my code the actual response and expected response in entirely different. can anyone trace out my mistake, thanks in advance.

Main activity

```
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<UserModel>> call = apiService.getUserInfo();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UserModel>> call, Response<List<UserModel>> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                List<UserModel> rs = response.body();
                Log.i("xxxxxxggggxxxxxxxxxxx",rs+"");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UserModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });





usermodel 


    public class UserModel {

        @SerializedName("profile")
        @Expose
        private Profile profile;

        public Profile getProfile() {
            return profile;
        }

        public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
            this.profile = profile;
        }

    }

profile  

    public class Profile {


        @SerializedName("isActive")
        @Expose
        private Boolean isActive;
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private Name name;




        public Boolean getIsActive() {
            return isActive;
        }

        public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
            this.isActive = isActive;
        }

        public Name getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(Name name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

Name

```
public class Name {

    @SerializedName("first")
    @Expose
    private String first;
    @SerializedName("last")
    @Expose
    private String last;

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

}
```

ApiCLIENT

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("test")
    Call<List<UserModel>> getUserInfo();

}
```

Its actual response is

```
[{"profile":{"id":"d712923e-62a1-11e5-9d70-feff819cdc9f","email":"trevor@ribot.co.uk","avatar":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api.ribot.io/trevor_big.png","dateOfBirth":"1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","hexColor":"#B60042","bio":"Trevor crafts elegant multi-device experiences with pixels and magic while tanked up on artisan coffee and Col-Erase pencil shaving fumes. He can also be found going on about Disneyland (again), playing video games terribly, or drawing a face on something.","isActive":true,"name":{"first":"Trevor","last":"May"}}}]
```

This is the response I receive `info.androidhive.retrofit.model.UserModel@9c6c34c`

This is my code the actual response and expected response in entirely different. can anyone trace out my mistake, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your **expected response** ?

Comment: [{"profile":{"id":"d712923e-62a1-11e5-9d70-feff819cdc9f","email":"trevor@ribot.co.uk","avatar":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api.ribot.io/trevor_big.png","dateOfBirth":"1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","hexColor":"#B60042","bio":"Trevor crafts elegant multi-device experiences with pixels and magic while tanked up on artisan coffee and Col-Erase pencil shaving fumes. He can also be found going on about Disneyland (again), playing video games terribly, or drawing a face on something.","isActive":true,"name":{"first":"Trevor","last":"May"}}}]

Answer (score 0):

> this is the response i receive info.androidhive.retrofit.model.UserModel@9c6c34c

Of course when you are trying to print the body of the response you will have this type of log, because you are trying to print **list of objects** i.e `List<UserModel>`

So if you want to check either you received something you can check the count like

```
Log.i("xxxxxxggggxxxxxxxxxxx",""+rs.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting JSON object you should add the `@Headers` tag in your interface.

e.g.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("Allusers/{iD}")
Call<String> doesUserExists(@Path("iD") String iD);
```

Also, you have to parse the response or convert it to an object you can manipulate.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
    if(response.body() != null){
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement element = parser.parse(response.body());
        if(!element.isJsonNull()){
            JsonObject obj;
            try{
                obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
                JsonElement elementA = obj.get("variableName");
                JsonElement elementB = obj.get("varialeName");

                int convertedElementA = elementA.getAsInt();
                int convertedelementB  = elementB.getAsInt();

            }catch (Exception ee){
                LOG.info("...");
            }

        }
    }
}
```